# How do I loop through a JSON object that contains arrays?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

How would I loop through this correctly?

```
{names:['oscar','bill','brad'],ages:['20','25','18']}
```

So i'd basically get the output:

```
names: oscar
ages: 20

names: bill
ages: 25

names: brad
ages: 18
```

Yes I know its a for...in loop but I just can't figure out how to get this output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe

```
for (var i = 0, len = obj.names.length; i < len; ++i) {
  var name = obj.names[i];
  var age = obj.ages[i];
  // ... whatever
}
```

where "obj" is your JSON object

Comment: yeah, that seems right, Pointy. 

Oscaar, why format your JSON like that, by the way? Why not { {name: 'Oscar', age: 24}, {name: 'Bill', age: 25} ...}

Comment: It's for a sort of DB JSON using localStorage. I want to store "rows and columns" rather than sets of objects. Id normally do it your way tho.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple suggestion. It seems to me, implementation bellow would be better for you

```
{ people:[{name:'oscar',age:20},{...},{...}] }
```

To loop through this

```
var a = { people:[{name:'oscar',age:20}] };
var array = a.people
for(element in array){
 console.log(array[element].name + ',' + array[element].age);
}
```

we have our main object in variable a and inside we have our array in people attribute of our object. Array have our person objects inside. so first person in our list is a.people[0].name
does that help? as you need to use closure with this array you can check this blog post. http://yilmazhuseyin.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/closure-in-javascript-part-3/

Comment: awh, interesting, how would I look through this?

Answer (score 0):

```
       var data = {names:['oscar','bill','brad'],ages:['20','25','18']}
        function loop()   {
           var arrNames = data.names;
           var ages = data.ages;

           var str = [];
           for(var i = 0, len = arrNames.length; i < len; i++)   {
              str.push("\nnames: " + arrNames[i]  + "\nages:" + ages[i]);
           }

           alert(str.join(""));
        }
```